# Linking if...elseif statements of Javascript with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want the Income(of database) to store amtV value in Firebase Database when I input the amount for Income.
I believe it is possible with if and elseif statements as it works in just reading the values but somehow it doesn't work the same while I want to direct where the amount should go in the database
I hope I made my problem clear.

```
//Insert//
document.getElementById('insert').onclick=function(){
    Ready1();
    firebase.database().ref('Budget/'+dateV1).set({
        Date:dateV1,
        Description:descV,
        if(type ==='inc')
        {
            classSelect=DOMStrings.classSelectInc;
            classSelect = DOMstrings.classSelectInc;
            newHtml = '<div class="item clearfix" id="inc-%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>'
            Income:amtV,
        }
        elseif(type=== 'exp'){
            classSelect=DOMStrings.classSelectExp;
            newHtml = '<div class="item clearfix" id="exp-%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__percentage">21%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>'
            Expense:amtV,
        },
        
            });
}
```

**PS: I am new to Programming and Coding.**

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine the conditional code into a JSON object like that.

But if you split them, you can accomplish the same:

```
document.getElementById('insert').onclick=function(){
    Ready1();
    let value = {
        Date:dateV1,
        Description:descV
    };
    if(type ==='inc')
    {
        classSelect=DOMStrings.classSelectInc;
        classSelect = DOMstrings.classSelectInc;
        newHtml = '<div class="item clearfix" id="inc-%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>'
        value.Income = amtV;
    }
    elseif(type=== 'exp'){
        classSelect=DOMStrings.classSelectExp;
        newHtml = '<div class="item clearfix" id="exp-%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__percentage">21%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>'
        value.Expense = amtV;
    },
    firebase.database().ref('Budget/'+dateV1).set(value);
}
```

So we now take three steps:

1. We build the initial `value` that we're going to write to the database.
2. We do a condition based on what the user clicks that

   1. Updates the HTML
   2. Adds a property to the `value` from step 1.
3. We write the value to the database.

Comment: Thanks,I will try it for sure and update you with the results.